# Node is running one exec per js file

Tags: windows, node.js, exec, child-process

Node is running only one Exec (child process) per Js file 
Is there any way where i can run multiple exec commands in  a single Js file?
In the async series function exec is stopping after i execute a command,
How do i make all three exec functions execute without coming out of the project?

This is what I have tried:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var fs  = require('fs');
var async = require('async');


var find = /regex/;

async.series({
one:function(callback){
exec('git ls-remote',{maxBuffer: 1024 * 500}, function(error, stdout,       stderr) {
    fs.writeFile(__dirname+'/idsandDates.txt',stdout, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        //console.log(stdout);
    });
    console.log('stderr Here: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error Here: ' + error);
        callback(null,1);
    }
});

}
,
two:function(callback){
var LineByLineReader = require('line-by-line'),
lr = new LineByLineReader('idsandDates.txt');
var commitId;
lr.on('error', function (err) {
    // 'err' contains error object
});

lr.on('line', function (line) {
    if(line.search(find)>0){
        commitId = line.split("\t")[0];
    }
});

lr.on('end', function () {
    console.log('hello');
    exec('git show -s'+commitId,{maxBuffer: 1024 * 500}, function(error, stdout,stderr) {
        fs.writeFile(__dirname+'/commitDateFile.txt',stdout, function (err)       {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(stdout);
        });
        callback(null,2);
    });
});
}

,
three:function(callback){
var find = /Date:/;
var LineByLineReader = require('line-by-line'),
lr = new LineByLineReader('commitDateFile.txt');
var commitDate;
var i = 1;

lr.on('error', function (err) {
    // 'err' contains error object
});

lr.on('line', function (line) {
    if(i==3){
        commitDate= line.slice(5,line.length).trim();
    }
    i++;
});

lr.on('end', function(){
    var date = new Date(commitDate);//--since='+trueDate+'--name-only --pretty=format:
    var trueDate = date.getFullYear()+'-'+date.getMonth()+'-'+date.getDay();
    console.log(trueDate);
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    exec('git log --since='+trueDate+' --name-only --pretty=format:',{maxBuffer: 1024 * 500}, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        fs.writeFile(__dirname+'/modiiedJs.txt',stdout, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(stdout);
        });
        console.log('stderr her1: ' + stderr);
        if (error !== null) {
            console.log('exec error Here2: ' + error);
            callback(null,3);
        }
    });

});

}
},
function(err, results) {
    console.log(results);
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE :

Hey,
I have solved the problem of executing multiple exec using the 'q'
Framework For node using promises and then Methods

Thanks a lot for those people who are trying to solve my issue :)

Happy Coding :)